# Fire multiple functions with single .click()?

Tags: jquery

I have a feeling this answer is going to be very simple, but I can't figure out what to even search for.

What I'd like to do is have one .click() event fire two functions in sequence.  Function1 clears the intended area, and then function2 is supposed to .slideDown().

```
    function function1(){
    $(this).parents('#div').siblings().nextAll('#div').hide();
    };

function function2(){
    $(this).parents('#div').siblings().nextAll('#div').slideDown(1000);
    };

$("#div").click(function1 + function2);
```

I've tried the follow, to no avail...

```
    $("#div").click(function1, function2);
    $("#div").click(function1,function2);
    $("#div").click(function1 + function2);
    $("#div").click(function1+function2);
```

When function1 and function2 are fired independently, they work properly.  It's only when I try to fire them together.

Thank you very much in advance!

EDIT:
Oh, and the #div markers are only placemarker selectors.

Comment: call both methods inside click method..

Comment: @RAB: You didnt mention that it requires a handler called this. and we  all were in an assumption that they are individual functions without any params

Comment: @Shiva, what do you mean? `click()` takes a handler, and `this` is clearly used in the two functions.

Comment: I mean to say the function1,2 has a parameter to which this has to be passed...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass a handler that calls your two functions in sequence.

In order for `this` to be properly bound, though, you have to use [call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to invoke them:

```
$("#div").click(function() {
    function1.call(this);
    function2.call(this);
});
```

If you call the functions "naturally", as other answers do, then inside `function1()` and `function2()` `this` will be bound to `window` (or to `undefined` in strict mode), not to the clicked element, so they will not behave as you expect.

Comment: Hooray!!  I kept reading/trying the answers, but none of them worked.  Now,  let's say I didn't care about them being in sequence...would the other answers have worked?  Specifically, the .call() would not have been required?

Comment: @RAB, nope, the answers would not work because the problem comes from the binding of `this`, not from sequential or parallel invocation. You will have to use `call()` or `apply()` (or `$.proxy()`, or similar) to properly "pass" `this` to the invoked functions.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  That helps tremendously.  I can now research that further to better understand.

It's a hassle not knowing where to even begin searching/researching.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you - Try it.

```
$(selectorForButton).click(
  function(e){
    function1();
    function2();
 });
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering, but for some reason this didn't work. It seems it needed a function.call(this)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `callback` as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#test').click(function(){
        one();
        two();
    });
});



function one(){
    alert("I am function one");
}

function two(){
    alert("I am function two");
}
```

​Here is a working [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gAwWE/)

Comment: Thank you very much for answering, but for some reason this didn't work. It seems it needed a function.call(this)

Comment: Ooops i forgot the colon `;` at the end, updated the answer check it now.

Comment: Oh, I hate for you to waste your time.  I received an answer that explained what I was doing wrong.  Thank you though!